Period of Pendulum?
Does anyone know why curved lines from $\vec {OA}, \vec {OC}$ are curved?  Is there some other property in the image below that is defining above mentioned curved lines in this picture?


https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Tatum)/19%3A_The_Cycloid/19.09%3A_The_Cycloidal_Pendulum

Not 100% sure but suspect the curved lines represent a solid shape for which, if a string pendulum wrapped itself perfectly around the exterior surface during oscillation, said pendulum would have constant period independent of amplitude.

@BowlOfRed Cycloid.  I don't see gravity in that equation linked

@Nick because gravity hasn't anything to do with the independence of period from frequency concerning this shape.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Cycloidal_pendulum

@MarianoG Your comment should be an answer, esp. b/c it's the correct answer.

@JEB It's kind of you, but really the provided links give the best answers.

@MarianoG but this sight isn't "Physics-Links-Stack-Exchange", it's Physics Stack Exchange, so I think members answers are preferable (with a links for further info beyond the scope of a PSE answer--no body reading a PhD thesis here). Some posts I've answered, like explain how QCD becomes an effective field theory of baryons exchanging meson, which is an actual 40 year research program for 100-1000's of ppl...yes: that is a link, with a brief explanation.
